# Increment/Decrement Custom ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView where it shows images and there are two ImageButtons that will be used for increment and decrement to show how many items a user has.
I have two issues the first is that the increment for one ListView when clicked will show 1, if I click the increment Button on a new ListView instead of saying 1 it shows 2. Ive been reading other stack overflow posts, but didn't quite get how to get it to work so I wanted to post my code and see if anyone can help out.

What I need it to do is to have it show 1 when I click on a ListView and then if I click on another ListView I need that one to start at 1 instead of 2.

The second issue is that the ListView cycles and shows what was previously entered for example if on the first 5 ListViews I click the increment Button 
once on each the ListView will show 1 , 2, 3 , 4 , 5 then if I scroll down to the 6th ListView it will show 1 the seventh will show 2 etc.

I am new to programming and any help would be very much appreciated.
If additional codes that ive written are needed please let me know.

```
package net.programmingparadise.duelysttracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by josel on 1/20/2017.
 */

public class ListArray extends ArrayAdapter<List> {

    int quantity = 0;

    public ListArray(Context context, ArrayList<List> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        final List local_list = getItem(position);

        ImageView cardImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImageView);
        cardImageView.setImageResource(local_list.getmCardImage());
        ImageView spiritImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.spiritImageView);
        spiritImageView.setImageResource(local_list.getmSpiritImage());
        ImageView setImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.setImageView);
        setImageView.setImageResource(local_list.getmSetImage());
        final TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCount);

        ImageButton incrementButton = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.increment);


        incrementButton.setTag(local_list);

        incrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                quantity++;
                quantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));


            }
        });
        return listItemView;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ListArray extends ArrayAdapter<List> {

    int quantity = 0;
```

Essentially what this does is that each Adapter has its own quantity. Where it sounds like you want each row of the adapter to have its own quantity.

In that case, I think the quickest solution would be to use `setTag` to set the quantity on `listItemView` when it's null to be 0. Otherwise, use `getTag` to get the quantity of that row.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        listItemView.setTag(0);
    } 
   final Integer quantity = (Integer) listItemView.getTag();
   // setTag again in onClick to quantity + 1
```

To handle scrolling, you should be using the "View holder" pattern

Comment: Im sorry for all the questions but when I put in "final Integer quantity = listItemView.getTag();" it states that the types are incompatible its saying one is an Integer and the other is an object how would i go around correcting that, is there something i can read to get this cleared up

Comment: You can use the IDE to fix it for you. Ones is an object, the other is an Integer. You'll want to look up "casting". I'm not sure if this is the solution you're looking for, though